# Check engine light is on but no codes provided when checking with reader

Tags: chevrolet, diagnostics, dtc, trailblazer

I have a 2004 Chevy Trailblazer.

My check engine light is on, but I'm getting no codes when checking with reader only blank screen.

How could this happen?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to [edit] this to add details. Title states trailblazer, yet tagged with Cobalt. Have you verified the reader is working? To improve your question, you might want to read **[ask]**.

Comment: welcome to the site! We would love to help you with your problem but we need some more information. Please edit your post and then flag it for moderator attention so we can reopen it for you!

Comment: What kind of a reader were you using?  Does the reader work on another vehicle?